How to get the binary version of an older release of varnish cache
How to get the binary version of an older release of varnish cache
https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/releases/tag/varnish-4.1.4
The above just contains the source, but I am not in a position to build because of dependencies like libtoolize
varnish-cache-varnish-4.1.1# sh -x autogen.sh 
+ uname -s
+ LIBTOOLIZE=libtoolize
+ automake --version
+ tr   \n
+ egrep ^[0-9]\.[0-9a-z.-]+
+ automake_version=1.16.1
+ [ -z 1.16.1 ]
+ set -ex
+ libtoolize --copy --force
autogen.sh: 47: libtoolize: not found


You can find packages for all these versions on https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/, which is the official package repository.

How to download this version, https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41 since clicking on it takes you to a new repository for a registered user

Here's a basic tutorial on how to install Varnish using packages on a Debian system: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/installing-varnish-debian/.
Replace the Varnish & Debian version specific parameters with the ones you're using.

@user352290 Also keep in mind that older versions of Varnish are only supported on older Linux distributions.

it doesn't seem to work in focal
repository 'https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

@user352290 Ubuntu Xenial is the most recent distro that is supported. Remember: you're running end-of-life software (with bugs & potential security vulnerabilities). These releases are definitely not maintained for recent distributions. Why not switch to a recent Varnish version? The VCL syntax should be compatible.

We are just trying to maintain a very old software and we don't want to end up with config related issues. What older version of varnish would be compatible with focal (i.e 20.04)

@user352290 I would recommend using https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60lts, because it's the LTS version we support. It's also the "oldest" one that supports focal.
